# How can I set up two-factor authentication (use both fingerprint and password) on my HP Pavilion laptop?

Tags: windows-7, security, hp-pavilion, fingerprint, two-factor-authentication

I have an HP Pavilion dv6z-3000 laptop with a [Validity](http://www.validityinc.com/) VFS301 fingerprint reader.  I'd like to set it up so that it prompts for both my fingerprint and password, but I can't find any such option for two-factor authentication in the (DigitalPersona-based) HP SimplePass software.  How do I do this?  Methods which use Windows itself or the HP SimplePass software are preferred.

The operating system is Windows 7 Home Premium x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do the same thing on a HP EliteBook 6930p a few years back and could not get it to work either. So what i did was the following workaround:

- I set a BIOS boot password
- I set the Windows authentication method to fingerprint

Comment: Better than nothing, but not by much...